CadQuery: how to select edges by shape
I have the following code:
base = (
    cq.Workplane("XY")
    .box(10,10,10)
)

top = (
    base
    .faces(">Z")
    .workplane()
    .box(5,5,5)
) 

How can I get all edges of the top box only ?
edges = top.edges() contains all edges of both boxes. Is there a way to only select top box ?
